# Does the "Incendiary Ring of Fireblazing" make Magic Missile a fire attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, spells, magic-items

Does the *Incendiary Ring of Fireblazing*'s ability to turn Basic Attacks into fire attacks change Magic Missile into a fire attack, as you can use it as a Ranged Basic Attack?

Comment: Do you mean the *Incendiary Ring of Fireblazing*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, *Incendiary* Ring of Fireblazing works with Magic Missile**

From PHB1 p159:

> **Magic Missile**
>
> *Special:* This power counts as a ranged basic attack.

From Mordenkainen's Emporium, p76:

> **Incendiary Ring of Fireblazing**
>
> *Property:* When you make a basic attack, that attack can deal fire damage instead of its normal damage type.

If you have an Incendiary Ring of Fireblazing, you may *choose* to have Magic Missile deal fire damage instead of its normal force damage, because the ring allows you to modify basic attacks and Magic Missile counts as a basic attack for all purposes (unlike some other powers which let you use them *instead of* a basic attack).

Comment: As a minor question. Does this give the magic missile the "fire" keyword?

Comment: @PatrickvD Yes. I'd have to go looking for the rule in question, but changing the damage type of a power always gives it the keyword for its new damage type.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes.

The Property for the *Incendiary Ring of Fireblazing* is as follows:

> **Property:** When you make a basic attack, that attack can deal fire damage instead of its normal damage type.

This is pretty straightforward. Most items that affect basic attacks also affect powers that count as basic attacks (see: *Iron Armbands of Power*). This ring and the *magic missile* power are no exceptions to this general rule.